# C# Console : How can i enter a value in LastName after i Enter a variable in the char variable?

Tags: c#, console-application

Here's my code :

```
public static void Main(string[] args) 
{
  string FirstName;
  string LastName;

  char MiddleInitial;

  Console.Write("Enter  first name: ");

  FirstName = Console.ReadLine();

  if (FirstName.Equals("null")) 
  {
    Console.Write("Insert middle initial: ");
    Console.Write("\n Insert last name: \n");
  } 
  else 
  {
    Console.Write("Insert middle initial: ");

    MiddleInitial = (char) Console.Read();

    Console.Write("Enter  last name: ");

    LastName = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.ReadKey();
  }

}
```

---

I can't enter the lastname variable at the last part of my code.
Anyone there more knowledgable who can answer my concern?

The output always went like this:
Enter  first name:Jason
Insert middle initial: f
Enter  last name:

```
After i press one letter it goes back to the IDE
```

The program output should be like this:

```
Enter  first name:Joshua 

Insert middle initial:F

Enter  last name:Capili
```

---

```
Enter  first name:null 
Insert middle initial:
Enter  last name:
```

Comment: `FirstName.Equals("null")` <-- This does not do what you think it does.

Comment: I can't explain _why_ what happens happens; but if you replace `(char)Console.Read()` with `Console.ReadLine()[0]`, you should be able to provide the last name as well. Also: As Dai just pointed out, you should have a look at your `if` loop (both condition and content, I would say).

Comment: please see again the edited question there is required program output needed that's why i put FirstName.Equals("null")

Comment: if i enter "null" the program should not promp the user

Comment: Thankyou Astrid E. i justr eplace (char)Console.Read() with Console.ReadLine()[0] and it work out thanks alot hehe.

Comment: You're welcome. (FYI: As the code currently stands, you _are_ prompting the user for middle and last name when they provide `"null"`, they just don't have any opportunity to answer. That may be a bit confusing for the user.)

Answer (score 1):

I try to execute your code, in my VS it works. Try this code:

```
 MiddleInitial = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
```

Or this:

```
 MiddleInitial = Console.ReadLine()[0];
```

Comment: thank you nika for this it really helped me alot God bless.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because `Console.Read()` [appends a new line to the input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.read?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Console.Read);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-6.0#remarks). When you subsequently do `Console.Readline()` there is already a line in the buffer so it sets `LastName` to whatever comes after the first character you type, even if it is empty string.

You can use `ReadLine()` for the middle initial (as a string) and just take the first character.